# Django+celery: how to show worker logs on the web server

Tags: django, rabbitmq, celery, djcelery

I'm using Django+celery for my 1st ever web development project, and rabbitmq as the broker. My celery workers are running on a different system from the web server and are executing long-running tasks. During the task execution, the task output will be dumped to local log files on the workers. I'd like to display these task log files through the web server so the user can know in real-time where the execution is, but I've no idea how I should transfer these log files between the workers and the system where the web server is. Any suggestion is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Do not move logs, just log to the same place. It can be really any database (relational or non-relational) accessible from the web server and Celery workers. You can even create (or look for) appropriate python logging handler, saving log records to the centralized storage.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the solution isn't to move the logs, but to aggregate them. Take a look at some logging tools like splunk, loggly or logscape.